# Spring: java.io.NotSerializableException: MapSqlParameterSource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Estou tentando um simples insert na base com Spring JdbcTemplate mapeando os parametros da query com o MapSqlParamaterSource e estou tomando erro conforme os dados abaixo:

```
public void adiciona(Conta conta) {
    String sql = "insert into contas (descricao, paga, valor, tipo) values (:descricao,:paga,:valor,:tipo)";
    MapSqlParameterSource pss = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    pss.addValue("descricao", conta.getDescricao());
    pss.addValue("paga", "true");
    pss.addValue("valor", conta.getValor());
    pss.addValue("tipo", conta.getTipo());

    getJdbcTemplate().update(sql, pss);     
}
```

Log de erro:

```
mar 22, 2015 12:16:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring mvc] in context with path [/contas] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into contas (descricao, paga, valor, tipo) values (:descricao,:paga,:valor,:tipo)]; Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException] with root cause
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource
```

Java Bean:

```
public class Conta implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4678852901357132238L;

    private Long id;
    private String descricao;
    private boolean paga;
    private double valor;
    private Calendar dataPagamento;
    private TipoDaConta tipo;

    //getters and setters
```

Alguem consegue me dizer como resolver este problema ?

Comment: A instrução SQL não está correta. Você pode postar o javabean do tipo Conta?

Comment: Postado João Manolo.

Comment: Uma duvida... Você criou uma instrução de "Insert", mas está dando "Update"?

Comment: Sim, para os "Inserts" com Spring-Jdbc, você utiliza a instrução "Update".

Comment: Entendi! Então eu acho que ele está sentindo falta do atributo (parâmetro) **dataPagamento**, já testou?

Comment: Então, se eu estivesse passando meu objeto Conta no argumento do update, eu concordaria com você. Mas como eu estou utilizando o MapSqlParameterSource para mapear os parametros e os valores, o Spring não me obriga que todos os atributos do meu objeto estejam preenchidos, entende?

Comment: Sim concordo. Bem, eu acho que poderíamos fazer o seguinte teste: você tentou substituir os parâmetros passados na instrução SQL pelo coringa "?". Creio que da forma que a Query está atualmente só funcione com a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Comment: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate funcionou perfeitamente.